# Plotting a list of Complex nos on Z-plane in python

Tags: python

I tried:

```
plot(z)
```

where `z` is a list of complex numbers, which plots `abs(z)` versus index.

```
plot( z.real, z.imag )
```

doesn't work, it says `list` doesn't have attribute `real`.

Answer (score 3):

If `z` is a list of complex, use

```
[k.real for k in z]
```

to extract the real parts of every number in the list.

Comment: +1 I want to say `map( operator.attrgetter( "real" ), z )` but I think I might have been doing too much Haskell...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it might work if you fix the attribute error.  ".real" and ".imag" must be performed on complex numbers as far as I know, meaning they won't work unless there is a j component:

```
>>> a = 2.5
>>> print a.real
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'real'
>>> a = 2.5 + 0j
>>> print a.real
2.5
```

It looks to me like in your arguments for plot(), you tried to use ".real" and ".imag" on a *list*.  I'd suggest trying to use ".real" and ".imag" on the complex numbers inside the list themselves.  For a list of complex numbers z:

```
>>> z[0].real
>>> z[0].imag
```

will call the real and imaginary parts of the first complex number in z, respectively.  There are many ways to do this I'm sure, but the following is pretty easy:

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = []
>>> for num in z:
...     x.append(num.real)
...     y.append(num.imag)
...
>>> plot(x,y)
```

Sorry that was so wordy, I'm really tired lol.  While I've never used plot() before, my understanding is that it can plot lists so that should work.